# No sé porqué este código me devuelve el mismo valor

Tags: jquery

El código funciona a las mil maravillas. Veo k no era necesario crear la variable cont y los errores k tenía eran lebes. Aquí está sucediendo algo con el switch pq cuando llega al caso 3, lanza las alertas del date1 y date2. Por lo k veo se superponen 2 alertas. En general saltan las 3 alertas.

```
    <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-12  form-group">
              <label>Cantidad de horas de los cursos imparidos en el exterior según:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
              <label for="date_fecha_inicio">Fecha de Inicio</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control " id="date_fecha_inicio">
              <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_fecha_inicio">Escoja la fecha de inicio</div>
              <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_fecha_incorrecta">Las fechas son incorrectas</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
              <label for="date_fecha_cierre">Fecha de Cierre</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control " id="date_fecha_cierre">
              <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_fecha_cierre">Escoja la fecha de cierre</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success align-bottom" id="btn_buscar_x_fecha">Buscar</button>


$("#btn_buscar_x_fecha").click(function(){

        var aux = validarDate( $("#date_fecha_inicio"), $("#date_fecha_cierre"));
        alert(aux);
        switch(aux){
            case 0: $("#alerta_fecha_inicio").hide();
                    $("#alerta_fecha_cierre").hide(); 
                    return true;
                    break;
            case 1: $("#alerta_fecha_inicio").show();
                    break;
            case 2: $("#alerta_fecha_cierre").show();
                    break;
            case 3: $("#alerta_fecha_incorrecta").show();
                    break;
            default: alert("Hay un error"); 
                    break;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque en los primeros 2 `if` llamas al método `.val()` con un string vacío como parametro `if (date1.val('')) { ... }` e `if (date2.val('')) { ... }`. Esto sobre escribe el valor que tengan las variables `date1` y `date2`. Luego el tercer `if` evalúa la condición `if (date2.val() < date1.val()) { ... }` con `false` porque en ese punto `date1.val()` y `date2.val()` son iguales. Finalmente, tu algoritmo siempre entra al último `else` y asigna el valor 0 a la variable `cont`. La solución sería remover el string vacío en los dos primeros `if`: `if (date1.val()) { ... }` e `if (date2.val()) { ... }`

Aquí puedes encontrar la documentación de como funciona el método `.val()` en `jQuery`: https://api.jquery.com/val/

**Actualización 11/05/2020**

Este sería un ejemplo de la solución funcionando:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
  .is-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
     <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-12  form-group">
        <label>Cantidad de horas de los cursos imparidos en el exterior según:</label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
        <label for="date_fecha_inicio">Fecha de Inicio</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control " id="date_fecha_inicio">
        <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_fecha_inicio">Escoja la fecha de inicio</div>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_fecha_incorrecta">Las fechas son incorrectas</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
        <label for="date_fecha_cierre">Fecha de Cierre</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control " id="date_fecha_cierre">
        <div class="invalid-tooltip" id="alerta_fecha_cierre">Escoja la fecha de cierre</div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success align-bottom" id="btn_buscar_x_fecha">Buscar</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    function validarDate(date1, date2) {
      if (date1.val() === "") {
        date1.addClass("is-invalid");
        date1.focus();
        return 1;
      } else {
        date1.removeClass("is-invalid");
      }

      if (date2.val() === "") {
        date2.addClass("is-invalid");
        date2.focus();
        return 2;
      } else {
        date2.removeClass("is-invalid");
      }

      if (date2.val() < date1.val()) {
        date1.addClass("is-invalid");
        date2.addClass("is-invalid");
        date1.focus();
        return 3;
      } else {
        date1.removeClass("is-invalid");
        date2.removeClass("is-invalid");
        return 0;
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn_buscar_x_fecha").click(function(){
        var aux = validarDate($("#date_fecha_inicio"), $("#date_fecha_cierre"));

        $("#alerta_fecha_inicio").hide();
        $("#alerta_fecha_cierre").hide(); 
        $("#alerta_fecha_incorrecta").hide();

        switch(aux){
          case 0: 
          alert("Fechas de Inicio: " + $("#date_fecha_inicio").val() + " Fechas de Cierre" + $("#date_fecha_cierre").val());
          break;
          case 1: 
          $("#alerta_fecha_inicio").show();
          break;
          case 2: 
          $("#alerta_fecha_cierre").show();
          break;
          case 3:
          $("#alerta_fecha_incorrecta").show();
          break;
          default:
          alert("Hay un error"); 
          break;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias x responder. A los 2 if, los modifique if (date1.val() == "") y if (date2.val() == ""). Ahora lo k está sucediendo es k el único if k trabaja es el de la comparación.

Comment: Te recomiendo que siempre uses `===` o `!===` cuando quieras comparar si 2 valores son iguales. Por otro lado, puedes agregar un `console.log(date1.val(), date2.val())` en tu código para imprimir los valores que retorna la función `.val()`. Con esto puedes identificar si los valores que estás probando cumple con dicha condición. En el caso que encuentres otro error, no dudes en compartirlo por aquí para ayudate.

Comment: Puse un alert k muestra el valor k devuelve la función validarDate. Me devuelve 3 cuando hace la comparación entre fecha y es correcto, pero en todos los demás casos, devuelve 0. Ya puse date1.val()==="" y date2.val()==="" y el resultado fue el k te mencioné.

Comment: Cuales son “los demás casos” que estás probando? Puedes dar un ejemplo de date1 y date2 en cada uno de esos casos?

Comment: Disculpa, no m explique de manera correcta. Estoy intentando validar 2 input de tipo date. Lo k estoy tratando de hacer es k lance un alerta cuando uno o ambos estén vacíos y además k la fecha final sea mayor k la fecha de inicio. Los otros casos sería, date1 vacío, date2 vacío o ambos vacíos.

Comment: El número k devuelve la función es para un switch k es el encargado de lanzar el alert correcto para cada caso

Comment: @CasinerO actualice mi solución con un ejemplo con las condiciones que indicaste en tus comentarios. Espero sea de ayuda 

Comment: Edité la pregunta. Ahora está el error k m está dando en este momento

Comment: @CasinerO actualicé el ejemplo de la solución con el código que agregaste en tu pregunta

Comment: Ya todo m funciona correctamente, pero no entendí cuál fue el error y pq se mostraba todos los alert si sólo estaba llamando a uno solo. Disculpa, sé k te he molestado bastante, pero necesito saber para no cometer errores similares. M doy cuenta k mis errores en el código no es tan garrafal, pero estos simples errores hacen k pierda tiempo.

Comment: El problema ocurría porque nunca ocultabas las alertas una vez que las mostrabas. Para solucionar eso en mi código oculto todos las alertas antes del `switch` y luego, dependiendo del caso, se muestra la alerta correspondiente.

Comment: Ya entendí la lógica. Muchas gracias, m has ayudado mucho. Cómo puedo hacer para subir tu puntuación??

Comment: No lo sé, lo importante es que aprendiste algo nuevo y que solucionamos tu problema 

Comment: Es verdad y eso es lo que vale. De nuevo te doy las gracias